# Can I safely purge IMAP in Direct Admin?

Tags: imap, purge, directadmin

My users on my server in DirectAdmin consumes a lot of diskspace in their IMAP folders. I see there is an option to PURGE imap messages older dan X days (e.g. 30 days).

For normal INBOX messages, this will not hurt my customers, because they have already downloaded these messages.

However for IMAP messages, I am not sure, since their mailclients synchronise their messages with IMAP, am I right?

So, if I purge these older IMAP messages, will these also be deleted on the client side? If so... I will be having a lot of angry customers when I want to take this action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your users use POP3 they have download the messages. But if you have the leave a copy of the mail on the server for 14 days option on, the mail is stil stored for 14 days. But they still have the mail downloaded.

IMAP is a mailprotocol that works directly on the server, if you remove (purge) this folders, people losing mail. So please leave the IMAP folders on the server. People that use IMAP, use the most diskspace of your server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I will just leave it this way. My provider suggested that it won't hurt my users, but I doubt they where right.